# Angular animation query style empty page

Tags: angular, animation, styles

in my 'home.components.ts' I have an animations part like this:

```
animations: [
  trigger('goals', [
    transition('* => *', [
      query(':enter', style({ }), {optional: true})
    ])
  ])]
```

so the side is presented as it should, but when I want to add some styles like this...

```
animations: [
  trigger('goals', [
    transition('* => *', [
      query(':enter', style({opacity: 0}), {optional: true})
    ])
  ])]
```

there is just a blank page (does not work with any style-attribute).

Anyone an idea what is going on? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You should add an animation part like this :

```js
animations: [
  trigger('goals', [
    transition('* => *', [
      query(':enter', 
        [
          style({opacity: 0}),
          animate('0.2s', style({opacity: 1}))
        ],
        {optional: true})
    ])
  ])]
```

this should do the trick, or am I missing the question?